# How to iterate email attachments after Get Emails action in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I created logic app and added following steps:

1. Recurrence trigger for every next min.
2. Get Emails action (include attachments: true).
3. Now have to iterate each email
4. while iterating email have to iterate all attachments under current email.

but I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of using a recurrence trigger, then get email action, consider using "When an email arrives" trigger instead. If all you care is new ones coming in that contains attachments. You will notice it has a "SplitOn" property, so it gets all the new emails in bulk, them spin off new instance for each email for subsequent processing. From there on, you can use For-each to iterate thru all attachments.

If you want to maintain the logic apps as designed, you will need to use for-each to iterate thru each email, and call a child logic app to iterate thru all attachments within each email. This is because the limitation of no nested for-each support - we're currently working on this feature and soon you will be able to create nested for-each.

Comment: I was only using "When an email arrives" trigger. but due to some incident trigger failed and could not process a lot emails and missed a lot of files. i was looking for plan B through i can reprocess those missed email from any email folder. but Get Email has only 24 max limit to read emails. resubmitting failed worked correctly after suggested by Microsoft support Team.